# Java .vs. C# Memory Usage and Performance

Tags: java, c#, asp.net

I am tasked with coding up an enterprise level eCommerce setup.  I know PHP, C#, VB.NET, C++.

I have reviewed a variety of benchmarks in respect to speed performance online and obviously the results are as expected, C++ hands down, C# and Java close enough its immaterial and PHP a strong last place.

I have been learning Java, not too different from C/C++ after all.

I have viewed some memory usage benchmarks related to both C# (ASP.NET) and Java (operating system stuff aside).

However, everything I have located trends towards the more simple scaler variables and normal "any language" constructs.  What I am interested in are memory and even speed performance benchmarks comparing complex objects.  Cant seem find a thing that is not biased.

I am not interested in the "I like this better or that better", thats simple preference.

I am interested in more concrete data as throughput and memory usage equate to server load and sessions serviced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd rather say Java is much closer to C# than it is to C/C++.

Comment: In the facts, Java is plenty fast enough; what is more, Hotspot at least is a pretty good JIT. Just write obviously correct code, it will pretty much always run fast unless you do a blunder. No idea for C#, never used it.

Comment: I use Java for private projects and C# for business projects on a daily basis and in my opinion they do not really differ that much. They are both fast enough to run on large-scaled web applications even though I must say I prefer ASP.NET for web applications since I got used to placeholders because they make things really easy to handle, even when using fully dynamic cascading pages. :)

Comment: Stack Overflow runs on ASP.NET MVC and performs admirably. So unless you are building something bigger than Stack Overflow, you should be fine with that.
I don't think you should worry too much about the performance of the platform, and instead focus on your own use of the said platform.

Comment: Stack overflow is somewhat akin to a WebBlog.  This is a commerce application.  The requirement and expectation in the white papers are the obvious maintainable/scalable etc. and traffic expectations of 1000-5000 page views per second.  I am trending towards C#/ASP.NET as I am far more comfortable (and like) the Development environment .vs. my limited exposure to Java thus far.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write fast and memory efficient code, then you should just write your code in this way. Software platform overhead is pretty low in Java and in .NET.

.NET JIT compiles code to native instructions, and most JAVA JIT's do the same thing.

I'm sure that benchmarks you reviewed is very synthetic - they just compare time of application cold-start(which is useless metric). Yes, software platforms that use JIT-compilation will lose there - because they need time to analyse and compile bytecode to native. In most situations, you can write applications with same or even better overall performance and memory usage than when using similar C++ code.

Just use language that you(and also your team!) like more.

Comment: Indeed.  Finding useful statistical information is quite difficult. Because we are under an NDA I cant discuss much in the way of details about the actual project which surely makes it difficult to get advice!  Conceptually what has been put in our lap to code up is actually pretty unique.  Due to that I expect higher memory usage than traditional eCommerce applications.  I did manage to find some rudimentary fair data today.  It appears Java is more memory hungry than C# and in some instances considerably more so.  Perhaps thats the JVM at work. Dont know.

Comment: @Rick, JAVA is NOT "more memory hungry than C#". It's only your JAVA code is more memory hungry than your C# code. C# and JAVA code can look similar, but it's may do absolutely differing things or use "more memory hungry" structures. 
As programmer you should use profiling to find out what is actually use your memory. Practically identical code will always use same amount of memory, detached of language this code is written in.

Comment: Thanks Rufanov...  I have decided to go C#.  I am far more accustomed to the Visual Studio environment than that of Java and the .NET framework I am at least familiar with albeit VS 2005 days. I am crunching through C# education much faster than I was Java (already know C++).  .NET pretty much has everything nicely packaged so I dont need worry about lots of external libs and I see Microsoft has brought MVC a long long way along refreshingly. Thanks so much for your comments and help!